# RSS Feed sudden error

Tags: xml, rss

I've had these RSS feeds running for some time and have just now run into an issue on one of them.

http://www.gamer-source.com/feed/news.xml (doesn't work)

and

http://www.starcraft-source.com/feed/news.xml (works)

Chrome is throwing the error...

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 20 at column 63: EntityRef: expecting ';'

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I've checked it out and can't find any issues with the content there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link>http://www.gamer-source.com/index.php?cmd=article&sec=news&act=view&id=581</link>
```

The "&" symbols are your problem.  Replace like this:

```
<link>http://www.gamer-source.com/index.php?cmd=article&amp;sec=news&amp;act=view&amp;id=581</link>
```

throughout the XML.

Comment: Is there any other characters we need to "amp;" or convert?

Answer (score 0):

The problems comes from the URLs:

> `http://www.gamer-source.com/index.php?cmd=article&sec=news&act=view&id=581`

Those un-encoded ampersands '&' are being interpreted as the beginning of entity references:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamer-source.com%2Ffeed%2Fnews.xml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0