# Twilio Redirect within a <Dial><Queue> probably not working

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a TwiML which is performing a `<Dial>` to a `<Queue>` (as described here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue)

In the url attribute of `<Queue>` I put the url to the following TwiML:

```
<Response>
    <Say voice="man" language="en">
        Your call will be recorded.
    </Say>
    <Redirect>
        http://my-twilio-powered-website.com/twilio/queue/dequeued/foo/
    </Redirect>
</Response>
```

The `<Say>` verb works beautifully, but the `<Redirect>` is ignored.

Is that correct? Because according to Docs it's a valid verb in the url of a `<Queue>`.

I have no error in the AppMonitor.

Comment: When you say the redirect is ignored, do you mean that the URL is not be requested by Twilio? You may want to contact help@twilio.com so they can have a look at this one, because it looks okay. If the URL is being requested, but then ignored, I'd need to see the contents of the file you're redirecting to.

Comment: The url is not requested at all.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you should contact Twilio support - help@twilio.com so they can check to see what is happening.

Comment: Just wrote an email to Twilio. But I have only the basic support, let's see if they answer. Thanks a lot anyway for your answer.

Comment: To be clear - I work for Twilio, and you'll definitely get an answer!

Comment: To be clear, so far my experience with Twilio is very good.

Comment: @MaxFavilli how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones who ends up here with the same or similar problem.
When I wrote the question I put a generic piece of code with language EN, in reality the issue was for other languages.
I opened a ticket with Twilio, (at the time of the issue) and they answered asking me to change the voice for those other languages, and it worked. Seems it was a bug on twilio side, related to specific voices.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400525/twilio-redirect-to-twimlet-in-a-php-script) with `<Redirect>` and it was because there was an ampersand `&` in the URL.

Does your URL have any of those?

PS. I would have commented, rather than created a new answer but i don't have enough reputation!

Comment: Nope, no query string in the url.

Comment: Sorry max - that's about as much as I know. Good luck with it.